# Magento 2 - how to change the product name in a configurable product

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

We have allot of custom products that we sell witch means we need to be able to ad those custom products to shopping carts for our customers.

Right now we are solving this with a configurable product called special and we add the needed information in a description text field. The problem with this is that is just dont look very nice in the email quotes that we send out when there is just a bunch of products called special, and they have to go in to the shopping cart before they can see what it actually is.

Is there a way to make the name of the product configurable aswell, so that the sku could be special or something and we can write in our own custom name for the product?

Would very much appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction for finding a solution for this :)